# Launch Sysprep.exe from C# Program

Tags: c#, batch-file, windows-8, 64-bit, sysprep

How could I launch sysprep.exe with specific arguments from my c# program ?

```
 public void cmdPrint(string[] strcommmand)
    {
        Process cmd = new Process();

        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd c:\\");

        foreach (string str in strcommmand)
        {
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(str);

        }
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        writeLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

    }
```

and I call it from my Windows Form Application,

`string[] cmd = { "cd C:\\Windows\\System32\\Sysprep", "sysprep.exe /audit /reboot"};`
                    `consoleBox1.cmdPrint(cmd);`

But it doesn't seem to start the sysprep.exe. I pasted the two commands in a .bat and launched it with,

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\\awesome.bat");`

but it doesn't work either (opens a black window and closes immediately)

Running the bat file from explorer works, so i guess I am missing some permission in my c# application.

In my app.manifest,

`<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />`

Is it possible to launch sysprep ? My application is made to run on Windows 7,8,8.1 and 10 on the normal desktop and on audit mode.

EDIT:

I tried the code without fulshing and closing the cmd but the program went to not responding

```
var procInfo = new 
ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Sysprep\\sysprep.exe");
                procInfo.Arguments = "/audit /reboot";
                var proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo = procInfo;
                proc.Start(); //Actually executes the process
                proc.WaitForExit();
```

Gives error :

> The system cannot find the file
>   specified/nSystem.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The
>   system cannot find the file specified    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()    at
>   Windows_SSD_Optimizer_Method_1.Method1.btn_all_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in :line 182/n/nThe system cannot find the
>   file specified/nSystem.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The
>   system cannot find the file specified    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()    at
>   Windows_SSD_Optimizer_Method_1.Method1.btn_all_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in :line 182/n/n

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Em8O.png

Comment: Why don't you just start the sysprep.exe? There is no need to run cmd.exe

Comment: but how do I pass the arguments /audit /reboot ?

Comment: cmd.StartInfo.Arguments

Comment: I tried starting sysprep.exe  with process but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Is your program running as 32 bit on a 64 bit system, if so you are looking in the wrong `system` folder.

Comment: How would i find that ? my os is x64 and I can start it from my C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe using cmd. My program is set to run on both x64 and x86

Comment: You can also write path strings like this: `@"C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe"` - starting with @ character.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Em8O.png

Comment: Tried your code and working - Win 7 x32 local admin.

Comment: I am running win 8 x64. It shows the file is not found.

Comment: For some reason, even the command prompt that the program opens with process can't access sysprep.exe.

I tried using process to run cmd which ran cmd with admin rights but still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows 8 x64 you should [be aware of File System Redirection](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/141590-solved-cant-run-sysprep-in-windows-8-rp/).

> When a 32bit application wants to access the System32 folder on a
>   64bit OS, Windows 8 will default any paths to syswow64 on the idea
>   that a 32bit program would really be looking for the 32bit files.

Try this path instead:

`@"c:\windows\sysnative\sysprep\sysprep.exe"`

```
var procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\windows\sysnative\sysprep\sysprep.exe");
procInfo.Arguments = "/audit /reboot";
var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = procInfo;
proc.Start(); //Actually executes the process
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: It works :DD Will this work on x86 system? or should I detect the OS and then proceed ?

Comment: Probably you will have to, yes. On Win7 that path does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for Windows Versions older than 8:

You need to compile your programm as x64 binary. If you compile it as x86 binary the system will redirect you to `SysWOW64` instead of `System32`.

If you need to be compatible with x64 and x86 you could also disable folder redirection:

```
 // Disables folder redirection
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);

 // Enables folder redirection
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 static extern bool Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(IntPtr ptr);
```

Comment: highestAvailable might not run as administrator if the user has no admin rights. requireAdministrator forces to get administrator rights.

Comment: Tried it, but it still says file not found. Tried running it through VS, `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll`

`Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified`

My UAC is already set to the lowest in windows

Comment: got the same exception here, thought this would solve the problem. I'll take a look a further look at it.